# SFML: How to draw/render from Screen class

Tags: c++, sfml

Game architecture is as follows:

// main.cpp

```
main() loads data from .csv/.json files.
main() creates an Application class instance as app and passes it data.
main() runs app.genesis();
```

// Application.cpp

```
Application::genesis() creates an sfml window
Application::genesis() creates a Menu class : public Screen as screen
```

// main.cpp

```
main() runs app.loop()
```

// Application.cpp

```
Application::loop() calls screen.step();
```

// Menu.cpp

```
Menu::step() calls draw()/render();
```

How do I either call Application::draw()/render() from Menu::draw()/render()
or in which way should I pass screen (Menu) the window to draw to?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I either call Application::draw()/render() from Menu::draw()/render() or in which way should I pass screen (Menu) the window to draw to?

If `Application::draw()` is a member function, you will need to give a pointer or reference to the `Application` to the `Menu` instances. This is typically done in the constructor, especially in the case of a reference:

```
struct Menu {
  Application& m_application; // The reference.

  Menu::Menu(Application& application)
  : m_application(application) { // Store it.
  }

  void Menu::draw() {
     m_application.draw(); // Use it.
  }
};
```

If you don't need the reference stored for the lifetime of `Menu`, you can also pass the reference to `Menu::draw()` instead.